# DllMain behaves oddly with g++ on Cygwin

Tags: dll, g++, cygwin

I'm using gcc v4.8.3 on Cygwin.  I'm unsure how DllMain() is supposed to behave in this context.

When I compile the same code with mingw, it works as expected, and I get the output:

```
Hello from DllMain 
Hello from main 
I'm a _WIN32 
I'm a __MINGW32__ 
I'm a __cplusplus 
Calling workhorse 
Hello from workhorse 
ret 1 
Hello from DllMain
```

When I compile it with g++ in Cygwin, I get

```
Hello from DllMain
```

and nothing more.  Help!  I suppose I could live without DllMain() in the g++ version, but it seems like I'm only a small step away.

Here is DLL code (dds.cpp):

```
 #include "dll.h"

 // #ifdef USE_DLLMAIN
 extern "C" BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(
   HMODULE               hModule,
   DWORD                 ul_reason_for_call,
   LPVOID                lpReserved)
 {
   printf("Hello from DllMain\n");
   return TRUE;
 }
 // #endif


 int STDCALL workhorse()
 {
   printf("Hello from workhorse\n");
   return TRUE;
 }
```

Here is the header file (dll.h):

```
 #include <windows.h>
 #include <stdio.h>

 #if defined(_WIN32) || defined(__CYGWIN__)
 #    define DLLEXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
 #    define STDCALL __stdcall
 #else
 #    define DLLEXPORT
 #    define STDCALL
 #endif

 #ifdef __cplusplus
 #    define EXTERN_C extern "C"
 #else
 #    define EXTERN_C
 #endif

 EXTERN_C DLLEXPORT int STDCALL workhorse();
```

Here is the main program (dtest.cpp):

```
 #include "dll.h"

 int main()
 {
   printf("Hello from main\n");

 #ifdef _WIN32
   printf("I'm a _WIN32\n");
 #endif
 #ifdef __CYGWIN__
   printf("I'm a __CYGWIN__\n");
 #endif
 #ifdef __MINGW32__
   printf("I'm a __MINGW32__\n");
 #endif
 #ifdef __cplusplus
   printf("I'm a __cplusplus\n");
 #endif

   printf("Calling workhorse\n");
   printf("ret %d\n", workhorse());

 }
```

Comment: Please do not include line numbers when posting code. They make it more difficult to compile.

Comment: You are defining workhorse as dllexport even when compiling the executable. This is wrong. You should only use dllexport when compiling the DLL.

Comment: I've edited the line numbers out, thanks.  I've also tried removing #include "dll.h" from dtest.cpp and instead referenced extern "C" int __stdcall workhorse().  That doesn't make any difference,  though.  Note that I don't even get the outputs from the #ifdef's at the beginning of dtest.cpp.  Sometimes, depending on small changes that I do not understand, I get no output at all.

Comment: You are probably getting a floating-point-based crash somewhere in the  runtime initialization code. I know I'm getting one. I'm not proficient enough in building windows DLLs with cygwin tools so I don't know where to continue from here.

Comment: Thanks for looking at it.  A floating-point error sounds a bit bizarre.  If somebody has working DLL code using DllMain() with g++ on Cygwin, I can also work backwards from it.

Comment: It seems that it was the printf() in DllMain() that was causing the problem.  I had also changed it to fopen, fprintf, fclose, as the DLL may not have a console, but it still failed.  So it was the act of observing DllMain that was the problem!  I found it by setting a global to 7 outside of DllMain and setting it to 42 inside DllMain, and removing fprintf.  I could tell that DllMain had run.